# using TempFileCollection closes before Process.Start finished opening

Tags: c#, wpf, process, using, process.start

In our C# WPF application we have some FileViewers (PDF-viewer, Image-viewer, and such) for files we've added to our WebDAV fileStore. When the file has an extension we can't open with one of our FileViewers and it also isn't a potential harmful file (like .exe or .bat) we use a `Process.Start` to open them.

Here is the code for this:

```
public void OpenFileViewer()
{
    if (OurFile == null || (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(OurFile.FilePath))) return;

    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(OurFile.FilePath))
        {
            // Local file not present in WebDAV yet
            Open(OurFile.FilePath);
            return;
        }

        using (var tempFiles = new TempFileCollection())
        {
            var file = tempFiles.AddExtension(OurFile.FileExtension.Trim('.'));
            using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(file))
            {
                var content = _fileStore.LoadFile(OurFile.FilePath);
                fs.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            }

            Open(file);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _windowManager.ShowWindow(new ExceptionViewModel(e));
    }
}

private void Open(string file)
{
    if (!Path.HasExtension(file)) return;

    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file);
    if (BlacklistExtensions.Contains(fileExtension)) return;

    if (ViewerExtensions.Contains(fileExtension))
    {
        _windowManager.ShowWindow(new FileViewModel(file));
    }
    else 
    {
        Process.Start(file);
    }
}
```

The problem that is currently occurring: The `TempFileCollection using` is already closed before the `Process.Start` is complete. If I would debug the code, the `Process.Start` works just fine, because the `TempFileCollection using` isn't closed yet. If I don't debug through it however, the `Process.Start` has not enough time and the `using` is already closed.

So, how can I keep the `using` open as long as the `Process.Start` isn't complete yet. Also keep in mind that the `Process.Start` can fail when the file is already in use or we don't have permission to open it or something similar. In these cases, the using should still close eventually.

I know I could just add a small `Thread.Sleep`, but that is always an ugly and wrong solution for these kind of problems.

I've also heard about `EnableRaisingEvents` for the `Process`, but I don't really know how I can implement this to close the `using` at the proper moment, without having it stay open if something went wrong when opening the file. I also can't add a `while(processNotStartedYet)`, because the user should still be able to use the application while the `Process.Start` is "running" (most of the time this only takes ms, but we don't want to get stuck in a while in case something went wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Process.WaitForInputIdle()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2(v=vs.110).aspx) after `Process.Start`, which waits for the process to enter an idle state.

```
Process fileViewerProc = Process.Start(file);
fileViewerProc.WaitForInputIdle();
```